# Modify "src=" in <script> tags before loading--without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, include

Basically, I want to do this:

```
<script src=" path + '/jquery.js'"></script>
```

(Obviously that won't work.)

I have a standalone page loading external scripts with `<script>`, but the URL needs to be prefixed with the variable `path` (because the page is run on different servers in different environments). I easily get `path` from the URL which always ends with "?path=**X**" where **X** is the actual path.

If I had jQuery, I know I could use `getScript()` to dynamically load external `.js` files, but jQuery is one of the files I need to load! I don't need anything too complicated here, no need to worry about encoding or file-types, it's a fairly simple situation except for the changing servers.

Comment: is it not possible to just load jquery from a cdn? Or is that not an option?

Comment: Not an option, it might be loaded on a system without a real connection to the internet.

Comment: Shouldn't you also be checking if jQuery is already included, as to not break the page you are including your script on? or do you not care about that.

Comment: @KevinB It is a standalone page and I can't see any way that jQuery could already be included. I haven't included it. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @brentonstrine Sorry, i missed that it is a standalone page, not script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use plain javascript if jquery not loaded. Something like that:

```
        var fileref=document.createElement('script');
          fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
          fileref.setAttribute("src", path + '/jquery.js');
          document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
          fileref.onload = function(){alert('loaded')};
```

Comment: is this asynchronous? or would i have to test to see when the jquery is finished loading?

Comment: asynch by default if from other domain, if same domain should be sync i think, see my edit

Answer (score 1):

You can load JS files by inserting them into the head with javascript, and at the same you can use your variable for the path when setting the source attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.async = true;
        script.src = path + '/jquery.js';
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        head.appendChild(script);
</script>
```